# Inbox sometimes not showing in StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Account association doesn't work, and Inbox link is missing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66860/account-association-doesnt-work-and-inbox-link-is-missing)

Sometimes the `inbox` button doesn't show in the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™.
Could we fix it please?

[image]

Comment: Never showing. ==> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66860/issues-with-revision-2010-10-7-4

Comment: Lol - For the "hot question" of `"If you had the power to remove one thing in your daily job, what would it be?" - I thought the answer was `"programmers.stackexchange.com"` ------ That made sense to me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There [was a post from one of the developers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66860/issues-with-revision-2010-10-7-4), the Global inbox has been disabled until the migration to the new datacenter is complete across all stack exchange sites.